# How to pass id along with date in datepicker?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Below is the table structure and only these dates are available in datapicker and when user click on those available dates i need to take price with that.

**Table structure**

[image]

**and here is my code.**

```
var availableDates = ["5-8-2015","20-8-2015"];

    function available(date) {
      dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
      if ($.inArray(dmy, availableDates) != -1) {
        return [true, "","Available"];
      } else {
        return [false,"","unAvailable"];
      }
    }

$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
    beforeShowDay: available,
    onSelect: function(dateText){
          alert("check");
    }
});
```

I didn't find any solution by which i can take price with the selected date by user.

Please provide suggestion.
Thank you.

Comment: i suppose ".bind" will be useful here but couldn't find the way to bind the price.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value this way.

```
 $(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
      onSelect: function(dateText){
          $(this).next().val();
          // $(this).next().text();
      }
 });
});
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, but please tell me how price value pass in this.

Comment: $(this).next() will take the sibling which is 'price' as per the image of your HTML and will take the val() will return its  value. If you can provide HTML over here I will help you to solve the issue.

Comment: well only datepicker control is essential here, which is <input class="form-control" placeholder="Jul 18, Sat" data-date-format="M d, D" type="text"  id="datepicker">... and i have updated original question.

Comment: as per my understanding you want to achieve 1) user selects the date from date-picker 2) according to the date you want price from html table ???